# PHP easily destructure array into individual variables to pass to function

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have a PHP array like this.

`array(2) { ["page"]=> string(1) "a" ["subpage"]=> string(4) "gaga" }`

I want to pass the contents of this array to a function call, of a function like this:

```
function doStuff($page, $subpage) {
 // Do stuff
}
```

How could I destructure this array into individual objects to pass to the function? The variables of the function will always be in the same order that the corresponding keys are in the array.

Comment: Why does it need to be "destructured"? Why can't you do doStuff( myArray['page'], myArray['subpage'] )?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to get the values out of the array and then [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) to call your function using an array of values as an argument.

```
<?php
$input = array( 'page' => 'a', 'subpage' => 'gaga' );
$values = array_values($input);
$result = call_user_func_array('doStuff', $values);
```

Or, in newer versions of PHP (>=5.6.x), you can use argument unpacking with the `...` operator:

```
<?php
$input = array( 'page' => 'a', 'subpage' => 'gaga' );
$values = array_values($input);
$result = doStuff(...$values);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure about the order of the keys you can use the newer `...` operator:

```
doStuff(...array_values($array));
```

Comment: New? The splat operator came in 5.6, which was 3-4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You just call the function with the array parts:

```
doStuff($array['page'], $array['subpage']);
```